# Meaning of "curious" badge

Tags: support, badges

The description of the "curious" badge is:

> Asked a good question on 5 separate days, and maintains a positive question record.

First, what qualifies as a "good question"? Second, how does one maintain a positive question record? I am asking this because I just got the "curious" badge on the main site, but I have not asked any questions recently. Please enlighten me on this.

Comment: See capital-m [Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges).

Comment: I was notified today that I had earned a **Curious** badge. I should be immensely happy and grateful. However, I have never asked a question on the main site. Perhaps the program has another meaning of "He is curious" in mind.

Comment: @AndréNicolas  You earned it on the meta site. Badges are separate for main and meta, unlike reputation.

Comment: The questions need not be recent. It does not matter how old they are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The description has been changed to

> Asked a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintained a positive question record

to avoid confusion with Good Question badge.

Per the [announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234259/259867), **positive question record** means 
$$\frac{\text{total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted}}{\text{total questions}} \ge \frac12$$
That is, this formula triple-punishes for a question that has been downvoted, closed, and 
deleted.

Also,

> A well-received question is one that's open, not deleted, and has a score $> 0$. If you ask at least one well-received question in a UTC day **and** none of your questions that day are deleted, downvoted, or closed, you get one more day of credit toward the badge.